# R Shiny: publishing leaflet maps with custom icons

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a leaflet map with custom icons and have the icons in the www folder for publishing. However after I publish I am not able to see the icons. My code is as follows and it works fine in Rstudio.

```
oceanIcons <- iconList(
  Rank1 = makeIcon("23-1.png", "ferry-18@2x.png", 36, 36),
  Rank2= makeIcon("23-2.png", "danger-24@2x.png", 36, 36),
  Rank3= makeIcon("23-3.png", "danger-24@2x.png", 36, 36),
  Rank4= makeIcon("23-4.png", "danger-24@2x.png", 36, 36),
  Rank5= makeIcon("23-5.png", "danger-24@2x.png", 36, 36),
  Rank0= makeIcon("circle2.png", "danger-24@2x.png", 48, 48)

)



    map = leaflet(map_df) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(icon = ~oceanIcons[map_df$rank],
                       popup=sprintf("<strong> %s <br>Expected Volume of Bike Departures: %s </br> Distance in Miles: %s <br>
                                     %s</br></strong>"
                                     ,map_df$st_name,map_df$outbound,map_df$distance, map_df$rank))%>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
```

Is there a particular reason why this method will not work with leaflets or publishing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that when you publish to shinyapps.io, that you send those files with, for example:

[image]